# How can I run an app with flash?

Tags: windows, flash

I have an app (GMusic for Windows) that when I try to open it, it says "You need the latest version of Flash to use this". However, I have downloaded flash, passed all the flash tests and everything, but still does not work. Any tips?

Comment: Where do you get this from? (as googling seems to indicate various version and location of download... none looks particularly trustworthy).

Comment: From the official site [here](http://apps.codigobit.info/2011/10/google-music-desktop-player.html). I used the beta, could this have anything to do with it?

Comment: @Darius Nope, its not the beta. I used the last official version and it didn't work.

Comment: Talking about flash.. there are 2 kinds of flash plugin - NPAPI and PPAPI. Depends on which version you are using looks like they put a note that they change the flash type to PPAPI. Have you tried that? (And maybe restart your PC for good measure)

Comment: Restarted. Still doesnt work. How do I change the flash type?

Comment: Since Version 1.9.15 it uses Opera/Chromium’s PPAPI Flash Plugin instead of Firefox’s NPAPI
https://get.adobe.com/es/flashplayer/otherversions/ Choose your Windows version and a PPAPI plugin -- This is what is written there.. sorry I haven't tested it personally as I'm running on mac at the moment.

Comment: @Darius Nope, still doesnt work on either virsion.

Comment: Out of curiosity.. you know you can access Google Music using your web browser right? https://play.google.com/music/listen?authuser#/now

Comment: @Darius Yep. Just need this for a number of reasons, including multimedia keys support, themes, not taking up browsing space and voice controls.